# Как кликнуть в неактивное окно игры? DirectX

Tags: python

Есть окно отрисованное с помощью `DirectX`, мне нужно кликнуть по определённым координатам **в неактивном окне**.

Как это возможно реализовать?

С кликами и вводом хорошо справляется `pydirectinput`, но я не нашёл информации о том, как кликнуть в неактивное окно.

**UPD:**

`Clickermann` так же справляется с задачей, но только в **активном** окне, а так же не позволяет пользоваться мышью во время работы.

Comment: Можете поискать в сторону отправки оконных сообщений

Comment: для кликов макросы хороши. попробуйте AutoHotKey например. хоть в активное хоть в неактивное, лишь бы точка нажатия по неактивному не лежала ПОД активным окном. в крайнем случае, он умеет перекидывать активность куда надо.

Comment: @puffleeck как раз и нужно отправить в неактивное окно клик, что бы при этом можно было пользоваться компьютером полноценно

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn, без потери фокуса\активности с того окна которым пользуетесь? пока только виртуалка на ум приходит. то окно в которое хочется потыкать(ну и макрос к нему) запускаете в виртуалке, а сами пользуетесь хостом. ну это так, к примеру.

Comment: @puffleeck думал об этом способе, но чёт это как-то слишком запарно, подожду ещё ответы других, может кто-нибудь придумал меньший костыль, но спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так делаю:

```
lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam)
```

Вместо PostMessage можно использовать SendMessage.

```
win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, lParam)
```

Разница между ними в том, что SendMessage отправляет сообщение и ожидает, пока окно-получатель сообщение обработает, а PostMessage просто установит сообщение в очередь.

```
set_hwnd = "Notepad"
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, set_hwnd)
if hwnd == 0:
    print("Окно не найдено!\n")
```

Тык:

```
import win32gui
def callback(hwnd, lparam):
    print(hwnd)

set_hwnd = "Notepad"
hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None, set_hwnd)
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwndMain, callback, None)
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ, у меня по каким-то причинам не проходит клик, даже по другим окнам, например калькулятор. Ошибок не выдаёт. hwnd нашёл с помощью `win32gui.FindWindow`

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn интересно, по каким? Хмм...

Comment: @Aycon по каким-то определённым

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn Проверяли что hwnd не равен 0 ? (пример добавил в ответ) Так же стоит учитывать, что не все игры\программы обрабатывают подобный ввод.

Comment: @Amgarak Да, проверял, и окно калькулятора и окно игры не определяются как 0

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn помимо основного окна, есть еще дочерние окна. win32gui.EnumChildWindows() вот можете посмотреть в сторону этого направления, мб не туда кликаете.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows

Comment: Спасибо, я проверю этот вариант, срок конкурса истекает через час, так что, вы выиграли, так как вы единственный, кто предложил вариант в качестве ответа